# search in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

need to check where the id on sheet1 is equal on id on sheet2 and then show specific cell in sheet2 corresponding to the collumn where the the id on sheet2 is equal.

Got this but is only shows 1 field

=SE(PROCV(A5;'Fichas'!B4:LL204;1;FALSO);'Fichas'!B196;"----")

Fichas is sheet2

Answer (score -1):

The formula is in Spanish so I'm not 100% sure what you're doing, but it appears to be an if statement. (Not sure what PROCV() translates to.) I think what you're really looking for is either vlookup() or [index(match)](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)